# Automating the MySQL query to get the weekly update

Tags: python, mysql

I have a database where I get the size of each table using the MySQL query

```
SELECT
  TABLE_NAME AS `Table`,
  ROUND((DATA_LENGTH + INDEX_LENGTH) / 1024 / 1024) AS `Size (MB)`
FROM
  information_schema.TABLES
WHERE
  TABLE_SCHEMA = "....."
ORDER BY
  (DATA_LENGTH + INDEX_LENGTH)
DESC;
```

I need to run this query every week to get the size of the table and check what is the difference between their size.
How can I automate this through the script?

Comment: A CRON Job would seem logical

Comment: Are you sure you are using MySQL as a DBMS?? I am pretty sure not

Answer (score 1):

You should write a python code and create cronjob which run any time you like. In the python script, make this query

```py
import sqlite3
import os
query ="SELECT
  TABLE_NAME AS `Table`,
  ROUND((DATA_LENGTH + INDEX_LENGTH) / 1024 / 1024) AS `Size (MB)`
FROM
  information_schema.TABLES
WHERE
  TABLE_SCHEMA = "....."
ORDER BY
  (DATA_LENGTH + INDEX_LENGTH)
DESC;"

# connect to your db
sql_connect = sqlite3.connect('example.db')
results = cursor.execute(query).fetchall()
# do stuff here, let's say I write the difference value to a file
# the value you get from the query after processe results
value = 100000

os.system(f"echo {value} >> log.txt")

sql_connect.close()
```

then make it a cronjob using bash check a easy explain here: https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/215767047-Creating-a-custom-Cron-Job